# Clang.cindex to find variable names in c++ code

Tags: python, clang, mutex, database-cursor

I have to use cursors to find mutex names in c++ code. When run it appends "class std::mutex" to self.mutex names.

```
    def analyse_cursor(self, cursor: clang.cindex.Cursor) -> List[Alert]:
        alert_list = list()
        
        for child_cursor in cursor.get_children():
            if str(child_cursor.displayname) == "class std::mutex" and str(child_cursor.kind) == "CursorKind.TYPE_REF":
                self.mutex_names.append(child_cursor.displayname)
```

Instead of appending "class std::mutex" I need it to return "mMutex1" etc. from the example code below.

```
std::string calculateUpdatedState()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mMutex1);                  // In this function we lock in the order mMutex1 then mMutex2

    if(mOtherState > 0)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mMutex2);

        mState = mState + mState;

        return mState;
    }

    return std::string();
}
```

I wanted to append a variable name to the list but instead it appends "class std::mutex"